# How to create dynamic jpa query?

Tags: java, sql, jpa, odata, olingo

Is that possible to create a dynamic "where" jpa (persistance layer) query with  getting from filtered uı data (Service layer)

Comment: Look at [JPA Criteria API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjitv.html).

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Using Criteria in a jpa query is a topic that's well covered by both docs and tutorials. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: I have different entities and properties and I do not know execute query which filter properties and entity sending from user I had looked up that api it is not useful for me.

Comment: also ı am using odata olingo framework which is building string query filter that is the main problem.how does the jpa understand it ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement Apache Olingo's `ExpresionVisitor` for OData filtering is to use HQL (Hibernate Query Language). Take a look at the [repository](https://github.com/sollersconsulting/confitura2017/blob/master/snapgram/src/main/java/eu/sollers/odata/snapgram/processor/FilterExpressionVisitor.java) where I did it. The trick is to map somehow OData's Entities and their properties to the ones from Hibernate.